# Make Java throw a StackOverflowError subclass instead?

Tags: java, subclass, stack-overflow

Is this possible? If I extend the StackOverflowError class, could a subclass instance be thrown on a stack overflow instead of the default instance?

Comment: Well, sure, if you rewrite that part of the JVM, recompile, and run through that.

Comment: This is a **very** strange question to be asking. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Nothing practical to be quite honest. I had the idea of implementing a StackOverflowError subclass called InceptionError. After exceeding recursion depth, the stack trace would print and the error message would read: "Limbo Reached - Maximum dream depth exceeded." If you didn't see Inception I doubt you will find this comical.

Comment: If you really want to do this, your best best would be a wapper at the outer edge of the program which catches StackOverflowError and throws your InceptionError. (You don't really want to do this. It's cute, but it's counterproductive.)